# Different Decision Tree pruning method

Tags: machine-learning, decision-trees, algorithms, data-science-model, pruning

I am trying to learn different pruning methods for decision trees. I have put together a list of methods below.

1. Reduced Error Pruning
2. Cost Complexity pruning
3. Minimum error pruning
4. Pessimistic Error Pruning
5. Critical Value Pruning
6. Error Based pruning

I got enough content to learn the first two algorithms, but I am unable to get enough content and understand the other algorithms. Can any one help me out to understand these algorithms thoroughly? Also, which algorithms are mostly used for pruning and why?